# EC2 instance slow after connect to CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I deployed a PHP website on EC2 Micro instance with OpenLiteSpeed web server and the website is working perfectly fine when called with its domain.

https://example.com

It's configured to work with any Listener Host so the is working fine when called using

ec2-123.123.123.123-ap.region.compute.amazonaws.com

I configured the CloudFront with the origin as `ec2-123.123.123.123-ap.region.compute.amazonaws.com` and it generated a cloudfront URL like https://blahblahblah.cloudfront.net and this link too working perfectly without any issues.

But when I change the Route 53 DNS A record for the domain from server IP to the CloudFront distribution the server was extremely slowed down.

Even when I call the site with either way

```
https://example.com
ec2-123.123.123.123-ap.region.compute.amazonaws.com
https://blahblahblah.cloudfront.net
```

The website is extremely slow and the browser network console is showing around 2 mins of TTFB wait time.

When I update the A record back to the IP instead of CloudFront distribution, the site responds in 80 milli seconds.

Initially, I thought it speeds up after a few hours but that didn't happen even while leaving the site for around 4 hours.

Note: I am not using ELB here, connecting CloudFront straight to EC2 instance.

Comment: Have you inspected CloudWatch metrics for the instance, or sshed into it and checked there? Is CPU high, mem usage high suddenly, or some other anomalies which you can observe?

Answer (score 0):

There are factors of static web page performance if you combine it with CloudFront but I doubt this is related to static contents.

- Use `local caching` for static contents as those will not change immediately.
- Your CloudFront distribution mode is compressed or not? if `Compress Objects Automatically = YES`, CloudFront will compress and serve the contents which is much faster.
- Try to use cache behaviors for static contents.